# Cutting strings into smaller ones based on specific criteria

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, csv, bioinformatics

I've got this largish (for me) script, and I want to see if anybody could tell me if there are any ways to improve it, both in terms of speed, amount of code and the quality of the code. I still consider myself a beginner, and I think that there are parts of my code that aren't maybe all that good - for example, all the variables I have to initiate before the main `for`-loop in the script, and the `for`-loop itself. Are there other ways of getting the same result?

This is what the script does:

First, it reads a large .csv-file (around 100,000 rows) with short strings ("peptides", looks like this: `AQSIGR`) and creates a reference `set()` from those. Then it reads a smaller file (around 100 rows) with larger strings ("PrESTs", which look like this: `TYQIRTTPSATSLPQKTVVMTRSPVTLTSQTTKTDD`, shortened) and analyses these in the following ways:

1. At every `K` or `R` not followed by `P`, cut the PrEST to the right
   of the letter (i.e. giving a first peptide `TYQIR` from above)
2. Also allow for up to two "missed
   cleavages", where the first and/or second `R` or `K` is ignored
   (i.e. `TYQIR.TTPSATSLPQK` and `TYQIR.TTPSATSLPQK.TVVMTR`, etc. from
   above)
3. Check every resulting peptide against the peptide reference
   set created in the beginning: only peptides NOT occurring in the set
   are of interest (i.e. unique).
4. Store the various peptides and PrEST data in an excel file.

There are various small details in the script as well (like ignoring the first resulting peptide from every PrEST), but the above points is the gist of it:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# ----------------------------------- Input variables -----------------------------------

# Input should be a .csv file with 2 columns (PrEST ID, PrEST Sequence)
data_file = 'Master Thesis 14 PrESTs'
protease_name = 'Trypsin'
#protease_name = 'Lys-C'

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data = pd.read_csv(data_file + '.csv', sep=';')
proteasome = 'Non-Unique Reference (' + protease_name + ') (UniProt, canonical).csv'

# Create peptide reference Set
ref_set = set()
with open(proteasome, 'rU') as in_file:
    reader_2 = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in reader_2:
        (ref_set.add(str(row).replace("'","").replace(",","")
                    .replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","")))
print(str(len(ref_set)) + ' peptides in reference')

def protease(PrEST_seq, a, type):
    if protease_name == 'Trypsin':
        if type == 1:
            if PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] != 'P' and (PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'R' or PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'K'):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            if PrEST_seq[a+2:a+3] != 'P' and (PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] == 'R' or PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] == 'K'):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    if protease_name == 'Lys-C':
        if PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'K':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

# Initiate variables
Peptide_list = [] # List for Peptides (resets for each PrEST)
ID_list = [] # List for PrEST IDs (resets for each PrEST)
Non_Uniques = [] # List for non-unique peptides
Non_Uniques_ID = [] # List for non-unique PrEST IDs
Peptide = '' # Current peptide (no missed cleavages)
Peptide_MC1 = '' # Current peptide with 1 missed cleavage
Peptide_MC2 = '' # Current peptide with 2 missed cleavages

PrEST_data = pd.DataFrame()
# ------------------------------------------------ Main PrEST for-loop ------------------------------------------------
for row in data.iterrows():  # For every PrEST (row)
    First = 'Y'
    PrEST_seq = row[1][1]
    Pep_Count = 0
    MC_Pep_Count = 0
    Non_Unique_Count = 0

    # ----------------------------------------- No missed cleavages for-loop ------------------------------------------
    for n in range(len(PrEST_seq)):  # For every AA in every PrEST

        if protease(PrEST_seq, n, 1) == 1:
            if First != 'Y':  # Does not count first peptide + MCs (part of ABP)
                Peptide += PrEST_seq[n:n+1]
                if len(Peptide) >= 6:  # Only appends peptide if longer than 6 AA
                    if Peptide not in ref_set:
                        ID_list.append(row[1][0])
                        Peptide_list.append(Peptide)
                        Pep_Count += 1
                    else:
                        Non_Uniques_ID.append(row[1][0])
                        Non_Uniques.append(Peptide)
                        Non_Unique_Count += 1
                        ID_list.append(row[1][0] + ' (Not unique)')
                        Peptide_list.append(Peptide)

                # ----------------------------------- One missed cleavage while-loop ----------------------------------
                Peptide_MC1 = Peptide
                m = n
                while m+1 <= len(PrEST_seq):
                    m += 1
                    if protease(PrEST_seq, m, 1) == 1:
                        Peptide_MC1 += PrEST_seq[m:m+1]
                        if len(Peptide_MC1) >= 6:
                            if Peptide_MC1 not in ref_set:
                                ID_list.append(row[1][0])
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC1)
                                MC_Pep_Count += 1
                                break
                            else:
                                Non_Uniques_ID.append(row[1][0])
                                Non_Uniques.append(Peptide_MC1)
                                Non_Unique_Count += 1
                                ID_list.append(row[1][0] + ' (Not unique)')
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC1)
                    else:
                        Peptide_MC1 += PrEST_seq[m:m+1]

                # ---------------------------------- Two missed cleavages while-loop ----------------------------------
                Peptide_MC2 = Peptide_MC1
                k = m
                while k+1 <= len(PrEST_seq):
                    k += 1
                    if protease(PrEST_seq, k, 1) == 1:
                        Peptide_MC2 += PrEST_seq[k:k+1]
                        if len(Peptide_MC2) >= 6:
                            if Peptide_MC2 not in ref_set:
                                ID_list.append(row[1][0])
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC2)
                                MC_Pep_Count += 1
                                break
                            else:
                                Non_Uniques_ID.append(row[1][0])
                                Non_Uniques.append(Peptide_MC2)
                                Non_Unique_Count += 1
                                ID_list.append(row[1][0] + ' (Not unique)')
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC2)
                    else:
                        Peptide_MC2 += PrEST_seq[k:k+1]
                    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                # Resets variables
                Peptide = ''
                Peptide_MC1 = ''
                Peptide_MC2 = ''
            elif First == 'Y':  # Doesn't count first cleavage (contains ABP)
                Peptide = ''
                First = 'N'
        else:  # Non-cleavable AAs - Peptide grows
            Peptide += PrEST_seq[n:n+1]

    # Appends PrEST data
    K = row[1][1].count('K')
    R = row[1][1].count('R')
    PrEST_data = PrEST_data.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[[row[1][0], Pep_Count, MC_Pep_Count, Non_Unique_Count, K, R]],
                                                columns=['PrEST ID', '# Peptides', '# MC Peptides', '# Non-Uniques',
                                                         '# K', 'R']))
# Writes PrEST data to file
PrEST_data = PrEST_data[['PrEST ID', '# Peptides', '# MC Peptides', '# Non-Uniques', '# K', 'R']]
ew = pd.ExcelWriter(data_file + ' Results.xlsx', encoding='iso-8859-1')
PrEST_data.to_excel(ew, sheet_name='PrESTs (' + protease_name + ')', index=False)

# Creates peptide list for Perseus and writes to file
peptides = pd.DataFrame(Peptide_list, columns=['Peptides']).join(pd.DataFrame(ID_list, columns=['PrEST ID']))
peptides['temp'] = peptides['Peptides'].str.len()
peptides = peptides.sort(['PrEST ID', 'temp'], ascending=[True, False]).drop('temp', axis=1)
peptides.to_excel(ew, sheet_name='Peptide list for Perseus', index=False)

# List for non-unique peptides
NU_peptides = pd.DataFrame(Non_Uniques, columns=['Peptides']).join(pd.DataFrame(Non_Uniques_ID, columns=['PrEST ID']))
NU_peptides['temp'] = NU_peptides['Peptides'].str.len()
NU_peptides = NU_peptides.sort(['PrEST ID', 'temp'], ascending=[True, False]).drop('temp', axis=1)
NU_peptides.to_excel(ew, sheet_name='Non-unique peptides', index=False)

ew.save()
```

Here are some input rows from the peptide reference .csv-file (100,000-ish rows):

> ```
> Reference peptides
> IEPVFHVMGFSVTGRVLNGPEGDGVPEAVVTLNNQIK
> LDAKKRR
> EILRNPMEAMYPHIFYFHFK
> KGPPPPPPKK
> MVVEVDSMPAASSVK
> ERNRNK
> QDWTILHSYVHLNADELEALQMCTGYVAGFVDLEVSNRPDLYDVFVNLAESEITIAPLAK
> EQFGQDGPISVHCSAGVGR
> ADIGVAMGIAGSDVSK
> ```

And here is some rows from the input file to be analysed (the Xs are not really there, but since this is confidential gene sequences I changed them here):

> ```
> PrEST ID  Sequence
> HPRR06    QGAWKTISNGFGFKDAVFDGSSCISPTIVQQFGYQRRASDXXXXXXXXXSNTIRVFLPNKQRTVVNVRNXXXXXXXXXKALKVRGLQPECCAVFRLLHEHKGKKARLDWNTXXXXXXXXXLQVDFLDHVPLTTHNFAR
> HPRR07    ERTFHVETPEEREEWTTAIQTVADGXXXXXXXXXPSDNSGAEEMEVSLAKPKHRVTMNEFEYLKLLGKGTFGKVILVKEKATGRYYAMKILKKEVIVA
> HPRR08    MDPMTVGRIEGDCESLNFSEVSSSSKDVENGGKDKPPQPGAKTSSRNDYIHSGLYSSFTLNSLNSSNVKLFKLIKTENPAEKLAEKKSPQEPTPSVIKFVTTPSKKPPVEPVAATISIGPS
> HPRR09    VPVSNQSSLQFSNPSGSLVTPSLVTSSXXXXXXXXXRNSVSPGLPQRPASAGAMLGGDLNSANGACPSPVGNGYVSARASPGLLPVANGNSLNKVIPAKSPPPPTHSXXXXXXXXXDLRVITSQAG
> HPRR10    DLQWLVQPALVSSVAPSQTRAPHPFGVPAPSAGAYSRXXXXXXXXXRAQSIGRRGKVEQLSPEEEEKRRIRRERNKMAAAKCRNRRRELTDTLQAETDQLEDEKSALQTEIANLXXXXXXXXXEFILAAHRPACKIPDDL
> HPRR52    STIAESEDSQESVDSVTDSQKRREILSRRPSYRKILNDLSSXXXXXXXXXVPTPIYQTSSGQYIAITQGGAIQLANNGTDGVQG
> HPRR14    MPKKKPTPIQLNPAPDGSAVNGTSSAXXXXXXXXXELELDEQQRKRLEAFLTQKQ
> HPRR35    MEDSHKSTTSETAXXXXXXXXHIAQQVSSLSESEESQDSSDSIGSSQKAHGILARRPSY
> HPRR02    EGFLCVFAINNTKXXXXXXXXYREQIKRVKDSEDV
> ```

The main output (first sheet of excel file, `PrEST_data` DataFrame) looks like this:

> ```
> PrEST ID  # Peptides  # MC Peptides   # Non-Uniques   # K # R
> HPRR52    10  31  2   10  9
> HPRR10    5   26  5   12  5
> HPRR09    7   25  0   13  2
> HPRR08    5   12  0   3   6
> HPRR06    7   45  4   10  15
> HPRR07    1   13  6   3   6
> HPRR14    2   10  3   7   2
> HPRR02    2   3   0   2   2
> HPRR35    1   2   1   3   2
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a limited understanding of the different parts of your code so I'll just comment on some details that can be greatly improved.

---

General:

A few things are not quite pythonic. You can make your code go through some automatic checks with [pep8online](http://pep8online.com/) ([PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the Style Guide for Python Code) and pylint.

---

About `protease` :

```
def protease(PrEST_seq, a, type):
    if protease_name == 'Trypsin':
        if type == 1:
            if PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] != 'P' and (PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'R' or PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'K'):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            if PrEST_seq[a+2:a+3] != 'P' and (PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] == 'R' or PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2] == 'K'):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    if protease_name == 'Lys-C':
        if PrEST_seq[a:a+1] == 'K':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

- from the implementation and the way you use it, it seems like this function always returns `0` or `1` and should probably return a boolean. Make yourself a favor and actually use booleans. You can now replace all instances of `if protease(foo, bar, foobar) == 1:` with `if protease(foo, bar, foobar):`. Also, in the function itself `if condition: return 1 else return 0` becomes `return condition`.
- You have 2 pretty similar conditions. By adding `1` to `a` if `type != 1`, you could make the 2 conditions actually identical.
- You do not need to get `PrEST_seq[a+1:a+2]` twice, just check if its values is in some list.
- For a string `s`, `s[i:i+1]` and `s[i]` seems to be the same thing when `i` is smaller than the length of s. Prefer the shorter if you can. You can also consider try-catch.
- It seems like you do not always return a value which is a bit odd.

Taking all these comments into account leads to the following code :

```
def protease(PrEST_seq, a, type):
    if protease_name == 'Trypsin':
        if type != 1:
            a+=1
        return PrEST_seq[a+1] != 'P' and (PrEST_seq[a] in ['R','K']):
    assert(protease_name == 'Lys-C')
    return PrEST_seq[a] == 'K'
```

---

About `First`:

You are using `First` as a character which is either `Y` or not. Here again a boolean would be more than enough.

- `First = 'Y'` becomes `first = True`
- `if First != 'Y':` becomes `if not first:`
- `elif First == 'Y':` is not required and you can do `Peptide = ''` and `first = False` no matter what the value of `first` was in the first place.

---

About loops

Your `while` loops can easily be transformed into a `for` loop using `range`.

For instance,

```
            m = n
            while m+1 <= len(PrEST_seq):
                m += 1
                stuff_about(m)
```

could be written :

```
            for m in range(n+1, len(PrEST_seq)+1):
                stuff_about(m)
```

(but my guess is that what you really want to do is `for m in range(n+1, len(PrEST_seq)+1):` and this could be an explanation for your 'out-of-range' exceptions)

---

About duplicated code :

You sometimes have duplicated logic, for instance on both branches of a test. If you keep things simple, it will be easier to understand and to maintain.

Also, you should not store the number of element in a list in a variable if you can just as easily check the length of the list.

For instance :

```
            if len(Peptide) >= 6:  # Only appends peptide if longer than 6 AA
                if Peptide not in ref_set:
                    ID_list.append(row[1][0])
                    Peptide_list.append(Peptide)
                    Pep_Count += 1
                else:
                    Non_Uniques_ID.append(row[1][0])
                    Non_Uniques.append(Peptide)
                    Non_Unique_Count += 1
                    ID_list.append(row[1][0] + ' (Not unique)')
                    Peptide_list.append(Peptide)
```

could become :

```
            if len(Peptide) >= 6:  # Only appends peptide if longer than 6 AA
                Peptide_list.append(Peptide)

                if Peptide not in ref_set:
                    ID_list.append(row[1][0])
                    Pep_Count += 1
                else:
                    Non_Uniques_ID.append(row[1][0])
                    Non_Uniques.append(Peptide)
                    ID_list.append(row[1][0] + ' (Not unique)')
```

Comment: Awesome! I added your code, and while PrEST_seq[a] is the same as PrEST_seq[a:a+1] (if printed next to each other), I get a "IndexError: string index out of range" for your version. Which is strange... Why is this so? It'd be very nice to just write PrEST_seq[a]!

Comment: PEP8: The only errors I get is that some of my lines are too long, nothing else. Although "not pythonic" is exactly the kind of help I wanted! I will read through the style guide, but was there something specific (other than what you already wrote) that you thought about?
Changed "First" to boolean, thanks!
The reason I use while-loops is because using a for-loop with range(len(PrEST_seq)) would make the range fall outside the index. Or am I missing some way to use the for-loop?

Comment: @ErikF. I've completed my answer. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I appreciate it ^^